# Caching domain objects in worker role

Tags: entity-framework, azure, n-tier-architecture

I'm designing my first N-tier architecture.  Many details of Windows Azure are still fuzzy to me, so I would appreciate some explanation/advice.

So far, I've plan the architecture to be as follows.  At the client-side is a Windows Store app.  At the server side is an Azure worker-role and database.  The Windows Store app communicates with the worker role via a Service Bus queue  The worker role communicates with the database via Entity Framework Code First.

When a particular screen is opened up in the client app (i.e. when the "session" begins), the worker role queries the database via Entity Framework Code First in order to populate the screen.  The worker role obtains the data as domain objects that are then returned to the client app as DTOs.

After the user finishes modifying data in the client app, he/she clicks a button that sends the changes back to the worker role.  This is when the "session" ends.  At that time, I need a way within the worker-role to examine the modified data sent back from the client app to determine which values have changed.  Doing so requires comparing the changed data to its original values.  My question is: where can/should those original values come from?

Which of the following two approaches are possible and/or recommended?

1. The domain objects (object instances) remain available until the session ends.  This way I wouldn't need to run the original database query a second time.  Which mechanism(s) in Azure would allow this?
2. Alternatively, when the session ends, the worker role instead re-queries the database.

Answer (score 1):

You could store returned DTOs in [cache](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/cache/): cache is way faster but limited in size so you have to consider your items can expire beyond the estimated lifetime or be evicted, in both of these unfortunate events you would end up querying the db.
Alternatively you can store the items in [storage](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/storage/): it might still be faster than querying the db and fit comfortably in your design, the items placed here are durable with no risk of expiration or eviction but you take the burden of cleaning up on yourself. It is more expensive too: storage write/read operations cost while write/read to cache is "free".

I am not able to pronounce myself on the possibility and opportunity of storing EF object instances somewhere. Because of my experience I prefer to gather the client's intention comparing the returned DTOs to the DTOs coming back from the client but it is just my opinion.

Do you know the expected lifetime of the items in cache, because of how you designed the client-service interaction? High confidence and short period of time favors cache. Are you able to foresee the maximum number of concurrent client-service interactions over the expected lifetime? Does it fit into the size of cache you can apply to your design?

I usually choose between cache and storage or combine the two: cache with storage as fallback. With querying the db as the last option.

Does it resonates with your scenario?

Comment: I would like to hear about what works best in your experience.  Please explain what you mean by, "I prefer to gather the client's intention comparing the returned DTOs to the DTOs coming back from the client".

Comment: @HappyNomad: my services usually rely on DTOs exclusively defined  for the client to service communications and I segregate data layer entities (EF or anything else), not surfacing them into the service. With that sentence I tried to express that if you cache the DTOs of the information/entity the client requested and subsequently the client post back the updated DTO to the service, the intention of the client app to manipulate data can be quickly determined by comparing the incoming current DTO with the incoming DTO you still have in cache, in order to perform relevant ops on the data layer